# Display missing parameters in cli help command on web page with JSONRPC

Tags: bitcoind, client, development, json-rpc, php

I am trying to get the entire contents of the "help" command to show up on a web page I am working on. Currently print_r($coin->help(); shows most of  it, but all of the required parameters, except <'["key","key"]'> under addmultisigaddress, are missing. They show up in the page source, but don't get displayed. I am assuming that it has something to do with them being enclosed in < and >, but I am banging my head against the wall trying to figure out the issue.

The web page shows:

`addmultisigaddress  <'["key","key"]'> [account]
backupwallet 
checkwallet
createmultisig nrequired ["key",...]
createrawtransaction [{"txid":txid,"vout":n},...] {address:amount,...}
decoderawtransaction 
dumpprivkey 
encryptwallet 
getaccount 
getaccountaddress 
getaddressesbyaccount 
getbalance [account] [minconf=1]
getblock  [txinfo] [txdetails]
getblockcount
getblockhash 
getblocktemplate [params]
getcheckpoint
getconnectioncount
getdifficulty
getgenerate
gethashespersec
getinfo
getmininginfo
getnetworkghps
getnewaddress [account]
getpeerinfo
getrawmempool
getrawtransaction  [verbose=0]
getreceivedbyaccount  [minconf=1]
getreceivedbyaddress  [minconf=1]
gettransaction 
gettxout "txid" n ( includemempool )
getwork [data]
help [command]
importprivkey  [label]
keypoolrefill
listaccounts [minconf=1]
listaddressgroupings
listminting [count=-1] [from=0]
listreceivedbyaccount [minconf=1] [includeempty=false]
listreceivedbyaddress [minconf=1] [includeempty=false]
listsinceblock [blockhash] [target-confirmations]
listtransactions [account] [count=10] [from=0]
listunspent [minconf=1] [maxconf=9999999]  ["address",...]
makekeypair [prefix]
move    [minconf=1] [comment]
repairwallet
reservebalance [ [amount]]
sendalert       [cancelupto]
sendfrom    [minconf=1] [comment] [comment-to]
sendmany  {address:amount,...} [minconf=1] [comment]
sendrawtransaction  [checkinputs=0]
sendtoaddress   [comment] [comment-to]
setaccount

setgenerate  [genproclimit]
settxfee 
signmessage

signrawtransaction  [{"txid":txid,"vout":n,"scriptPubKey":hex},...] [,...] [sighashtype="ALL"]
stop
submitblock  [optional-params-obj]
validateaddress 
verifymessage`

The page source shows:

`addmultisigaddress <nrequired> <'["key","key"]'> [account]
backupwallet <destination>
checkwallet
createmultisig nrequired ["key",...]
createrawtransaction [{"txid":txid,"vout":n},...] {address:amount,...}
decoderawtransaction <hex string>
dumpprivkey <paycoinaddress>
encryptwallet <passphrase>
getaccount <paycoinaddress>
getaccountaddress <account>
getaddressesbyaccount <account>
getbalance [account] [minconf=1]
getblock <hash> [txinfo] [txdetails]
getblockcount
getblockhash <index>
getblocktemplate [params]
getcheckpoint
getconnectioncount
getdifficulty
getgenerate
gethashespersec
getinfo
getmininginfo
getnetworkghps
getnewaddress [account]
getpeerinfo
getrawmempool
getrawtransaction <txid> [verbose=0]
getreceivedbyaccount <account> [minconf=1]
getreceivedbyaddress <paycoinaddress> [minconf=1]
gettransaction <txid>
gettxout "txid" n ( includemempool )
getwork [data]
help [command]
importprivkey <paycoinprivkey> [label]
keypoolrefill
listaccounts [minconf=1]
listaddressgroupings
listminting [count=-1] [from=0]
listreceivedbyaccount [minconf=1] [includeempty=false]
listreceivedbyaddress [minconf=1] [includeempty=false]
listsinceblock [blockhash] [target-confirmations]
listtransactions [account] [count=10] [from=0]
listunspent [minconf=1] [maxconf=9999999]  ["address",...]
makekeypair [prefix]
move <fromaccount> <toaccount> <amount> [minconf=1] [comment]
repairwallet
reservebalance [<reserve> [amount]]
sendalert <message> <privatekey> <minver> <maxver> <priority> <id> [cancelupto]
sendfrom <fromaccount> <topaycoinaddress> <amount> [minconf=1] [comment] [comment-to]
sendmany <fromaccount> {address:amount,...} [minconf=1] [comment]
sendrawtransaction <hex string> [checkinputs=0]
sendtoaddress <paycoinaddress> <amount> [comment] [comment-to]
setaccount <paycoinaddress> <account>
setgenerate <generate> [genproclimit]
settxfee <amount>
signmessage <paycoinaddress> <message>
signrawtransaction <hex string> [{"txid":txid,"vout":n,"scriptPubKey":hex},...] [<privatekey1>,...] [sighashtype="ALL"]
stop
submitblock <hex data> [optional-params-obj]
validateaddress <paycoinaddress>
verifymessage <paycoinaddress> <signature> <message>`

What gives? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

It's interpreting the `<>`'s as html.

Enclose the help string with `<code>$string</code>`, or run htmlspecialchars on the string.